# Redirect to an AngularJS state from email link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email, redirect

I want to redirect my users from an email link to a certain state in my Angular app. My app is a single page application, which means I can't simply redirect the user to the URL of the state.

So far, I tried to use **URL parameters:**

**This link**, let's say to go to the menu, is sent in the email to users => `https://mywebsite.com/index?state=menu`

In the main controller of my app, I use **the following JavaScript function** when user lands :

```
 function checkRedirectFromEmail(){
    var stateParam = getParam('state');
    $rootScope.gotoState('tabs.'+stateParam);
    // $location.url($location.path()); // I TRIED THIS, NO SUCCESS
    // $location.search('state', null); // I TRIED THIS TOO, NO SUCCESS
}
```

Where the function **getParam()** is:

```
 function getParam(param) {
    var vars = {};
    window.location.href.replace( location.hash, '' ).replace( 
        /[?&]+([^=&]+)=?([^&]*)?/gi, // regexp
        function( m, key, value ) { // callback
            vars[key] = value !== undefined ? value : '';
        }
    );
    if ( param ) {
        return vars[param] ? vars[param] : null;    
    }
    return vars;
}
```

And the function **gotoState()** is:

```
 $rootScope.gotoState = function(stateName) {
    $state.go(stateName, {}, { location: false } ); 
};
```

Finally, **here are the important states and parameters in my routing logic:**

```
 $stateProvider
  .state('tabs', {
    url: "/tabs",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })
  .state('tabs.index', {
    url: "/",
    cache:false,
    views: {
      'index-tab': {
        templateUrl: "home.html"
      }
    }
  })
})
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
```

At the moment, **users are redirected but**:

- I have to add "index" in my URL just so my parameters are read (normally, it's just `https://mywebsite.com/#/`).
- The URL remains "dirty" with the parameters, and I would like to clear the parameters. I tried several methods (see in my code), but it didn't work properly.

**MY QUESTION:**

Is there another way to redirect users than using URL parameters to redirect a user from an email to a certain state of my application? **If not**, is there a way to make it cleaner than what I have at the moment (clear url parameters, not having to add "index" in the url)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use angular components in a better way to pass values over the link

Comment: Use html5Mode(true) for hash removal and add  <base href="/"> in your html file

Comment: Are you using the angularjs default router or the ui-router?

Comment: @praveenkumars I tried it, but now my URL parameters are not recognized (my getParam function returns null).

Comment: @VarvarigosEmmanouil I'm using Ionic framework with ui-router.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution to this (email redirect to specific application state) that I have implemented in a project I participated is to handle this with state parameters that ui-router supports.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: "/home/:redirectTo",
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams, $state) {

            // based on redirectTo stateparam you can redirect the user to
            // the desired state. eg: /home/results -> results page
            $state.go($stateParams.redirectTo, {} );
        }
    })
```

So when you click on a link like: "myIp/home/results" will redirect you to myIp/results if the state results has url 'results'.